# R, function which returns the file and the summary of the same file

Tags: r, statistics, analytics

I have the following code in R:

```
getmonitor<- function(id,directory,summarize=FALSE) {
    a<- "C:/Users/UNI/Documents/Coursera/archivosR/"

    b<- paste(a,directory,"/",sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(id)),".csv",sep="")

    c<- read.csv(b)

    if(summarize) {
        print(summary(c))
    }else {
        return(c)
    }
}
```

What I try to do is that if `summarize =FALSE`, the functions just returns the file and that works fine in my function. However, if `summarize=TRUE` , the functions returns the summary which is correct but if I write head() for a value, which is equal to my function in TRUE mode, the result is the summary and I want the result of head to be the file.

Comment: Why don't you show in code, what you are running, what you expect, and what you get.

Comment: could it be as simple as after `print(summary(c))` add another `return(c)`?

Comment: For example if I set true in my function and I run head(a), the result is the summary, but  I want the file as a result.

Comment: "but if I write head() for a value, which is equal to my function in TRUE mode, the result is the summary and I want the result of head to be the file." What does that mean?

Comment: I´ve tried to add another return(c) after print (summary(c) but the results are the same !

Comment: For example:  a<- getmonitor(.....summarize=TRUE) and then head(a) the result is the summary of the file and not just the file that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you passed TRUE to summarize, it bypassed the return(c) statement, so R decided to return the summary.  Since you want to return the data frame c for all cases, you just need to put it outside your if/else structure.

Modifying your if/else structure to:

```
getmonitor<- function(id,directory,summarize=FALSE) {
    a<- "C:/Users/UNI/Documents/Coursera/archivosR/"

    b<- paste(a,directory,"/",sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(id)),".csv",sep="")

    c<- read.csv(b)

    if(summarize)
        print(summary(c))

    return(c)
}
```

Gives me the desired output:

```
> data <- getmonitor(1,"specdata",TRUE)
         Date         sulfate          nitrate             ID   
 2003-01-01:   1   Min.   : 0.613   Min.   :0.1180   Min.   :1  
 2003-01-02:   1   1st Qu.: 2.210   1st Qu.:0.2835   1st Qu.:1  
 2003-01-03:   1   Median : 2.870   Median :0.4530   Median :1  
 2003-01-04:   1   Mean   : 3.881   Mean   :0.5499   Mean   :1  
 2003-01-05:   1   3rd Qu.: 4.730   3rd Qu.:0.6635   3rd Qu.:1  
 2003-01-06:   1   Max.   :19.100   Max.   :1.8300   Max.   :1  
 (Other)   :1455   NA's   :1344     NA's   :1339                
> head(data)
        Date sulfate nitrate ID
1 2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
2 2003-01-02      NA      NA  1
3 2003-01-03      NA      NA  1
4 2003-01-04      NA      NA  1
5 2003-01-05      NA      NA  1
6 2003-01-06      NA      NA  1
```

Comment: It was so easy, huge thanks from Peru. I'll use it in the course I´m taking from Coursera !